# htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've rebuilt a site using a CMS and I want to make the old urls point to the new pages. I'm having trouble because the old URL looks like this: `?secc=country_club`. For instance, `domain.com?secc=country_club`.

I would like to either have a rule for each url or have it rewrite the `?secc=country-club` to just `country-club`

This is what I have tried, without any success:

```
RewriteRule ^secc-([^-]*)$ /?secc=$1 [L]
```

I think it has something to do with the ? in the url

Also if it helps, I am using joomla and I do have sh404sef.

Comment: are there other possible values of 'secc' ?  do you need to replace '_' to '-' ? is this the result you'd like to achieve ?

Comment: Yes there are multiple urls such as '?secc=desarrollo' but then there is one more type like so '?secc=desarrollo&sub=planos'

Is there any way I can rewrite the urls individually into something new? Ive tried the online generators but none of them have worked, i think it has something to do with the '?' but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^secc=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1? [R,L]
```

This will redirect http://example.com/?secc=MYPAGE to http://example.com/MYPAGE

Comment: ok this gets me somewhere but this it is putting in the entire file path

Comment: it changed the url to domain.com/var/chroot/home/content/m/e/r/accoutnname/html/newsite/desarrollo

Comment: I edited the answer a bit (added RewriteBase). If the site is in a subfolder, just replace / with /my/sub/folder/

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write '=' after ^secc:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^?secc=(.*)$ "$1" [QSA]
```

Comment: Still not working but let me rephrase, say I wanted to add each url has its own rule, how can I make it say  domain.com?secc=test_page -> domain.com/test-page

Comment: and would i be able to copy the rule but change the url, for each url?

Comment: 500 error when i load the page. See my comemnt above for the other guys solution. It almost works but nothing, any ideas?